# Error trying to decode json for reading tweepy tweets

Tags: python, tweepy, jsondecoder

I'm getting an error ValueError: I/O operation on closed file. when using the following code, the rest of my code seems to be working OK, any ideas?

```
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, 'r')

for line in tweets_file:
   tweet = json.loads(line)
   tweets_data.append(tweet)

    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-722708c7e759> in <module>()
      1 # Read in tweets and store in list: tweets_data
----> 2 for line in tweets_file:
      3   tweet = json.loads(line)
      4   tweets_data.append(tweet)

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to solve this you can use the `with` keyword

```
with open('filename.extention', 'r') as myfile:
    do you thing in here
```